# Generic method (bounded type) vs inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a typical question what is better and I think as always the answer is it depends, but I'd like to clarify it anyway. So there are two methods:

```java
public static <A extends Animal, F extends Food> void feed(A animal, F food) {
    animal.setFood(food);
}

public static void feed(Animal animal, Food food) {
    animal.setFood(food);
}
```

And the logic:

```java
Cat cat = new Cat(); // Cat is a child of Animal
Dog dog = new Dog(); // Dog is a child of Animal

Pork pork = new Pork(); // Pork is a child of Food
pork.setName("Whiskas");
Beef beef = new Beef(); // Beef is a child of Food
beef.setName("Pedigree");

AnimalService.feed(cat, beef);
AnimalService.feed(dog, pork);

cat.eat(); // prints I'm eating Pedigree
dog.eat(); // prints I'm eating Whiskas
```

I understand that there is a conflict of method signatures due to the type erasure, so my question is not "Why I can't have these two methods in the same time?", but rather "Which method would you choose?".

Comment: Counter-question: What benefit do we get by introducing the generic parameter in the 1st approach? I see none, hence I would default to the 2nd approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, it depends. You need to keep in mind that generics are a compile-time tool to help the compiler do some checks and spit out errors if you violate the constraints.

In your case you don't seem to have any constraints to violate apart from the upper bound for the parameter types (`Animal` and `Food`) so you don't gain anything from using generics - hence I'd choose the plain inheritance based approach.

However, consider you're changing your `Animal` interface to define the kind of food the animal needs (thus adding a constraint that inheritance can't help you enforce at compile time):

```
interface Animal<F extends Food> { ... }

class DogFood implements Food { ... }
class CatFood implements Food { ... }
class Whiskas extends CatFood { ... }

class Dog implements Animal<DogFood> { ... }
class Cat implements Animal<CatFood> { ... }
```

Now `feed()` could use generics to let the compiler help you choose the right type of food:

```
<F extends Food> void feed(Animal<F> animal, F food) { ... }

//this should compile because Cat defines Food needs to be CatFood
feed(new Cat(), new CatFood());

//this should also compile because Whiskas is CatFood
feed(new Cat(), new Whiskas());

//this shouldn't compile because DogFood is not CatFood
feed(new Cat(), new DogFood());
```